# Python: Printing the result of a function returns "None"

Tags: python, debugging, loops

I have some python code, the translate_string method returns the correct value `nevmban` but then after it prints "None".

```
def secret_translate(letter):
    code = ord(letter)-ord('a')
    code = (code+13)%26
    newCode = chr(code+ord('a'))
    return newCode

def translate_string(string):

    newMsg = ''
    i = 0
    while i < (len(string)):

        print(secret_translate(string[i]),end='')
        i= i+1 

print(translate_string("arizona"))
```

The program prints:

```
nevmbanNone
```

I expect it to print `nevmban` Where is the "None" coming from?

Comment: You need to post some more code.. And what does your `secret` variable contains??

Comment: That's not the output .. you have infinite recursion here.

Comment: You can replace `i = i+1` with `i += 1`, unrelated to your issue.

Comment: @RohitJain sorry...

    print(underground_code("arizona"))
should translate to nevmban but its transating to nevmbanNone

PS. underground_code is a function before this block of code. That function has the translating algorithm, it works it is tested, but i am annoyed very much by None printing at the end when printed. I am sorry if the code was badly written, I am a nooob

Comment: Where do you have your print?? Inside while or outside it?? If it is inside.. Then why are you calling the same function from inside.. for doing different task??  ** POST your Complete code **

Comment: @RohitJain disregard the other BS look at my new code that I edited. Hope that helps.

Comment: @anon_nerd.. Replace your `print(translate_string("arizona"))` with `translate_string("arizona")`.. This method doesn't return anything... That's why you are getting `None`

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry for the hassle. Can you briefly explain why it was doing the none though??

Comment: @anon_nerd see my answer for an explanation of why None is added.

Comment: @anon_nerd I also added an alternative version of your translate routine to my answer.

Comment: `str.translate`...in older versions of Python, I'd just use `.encode('rot_13')`

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the result of your `translate_string` function, which is `None`, as there is no explicit `return` statement.

Comment: How do I fix it using the return function and letters going sideways, not up and down?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the print method like this:

```
print(underground_code(secret[i]),end='')
```

You are passing just one character in the function instead of the whole string.  It will keep on checking the first character in your while loop:

```
while i < (len(secret)):
```

The above `while` will run only once.  And the next function call your `len(secret)` will be 1.

*Of course, ignore what I said if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have the translation table, you really don't need to implement translation mechanisms. You have them built in `string`:

```
import string

fromlist="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
tolist = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
transtable = string.maketrans(fromlist, tolist)

mycypertext="FCJJM UMPJB"
print string.translate(mycyphertext, transtable) #will print hello world
```

Comment: +1 nice and compact solution, probably also performs quite well for really large strings

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, thanks! I have taken a weird challenge to read all the Python STL documentation. You would be surprised how many goodies Python has !

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, yes, a great goodie. However, from my little experience with teaching Python for newbies, I find that their syntax is harder to get compared to `for x in somelist: do something ...`

Answer (score 0):

You print the letters of the translated word as you go, I would recommend returning the translated word from the function instead. The fact that you see None printed behind your translated word is because inside the function you print the word, and outside the function you print the result of the function. The function has no result (no `return` statement) and the default is None. Printing this leads to the None being appended at the end of the string that was already printed inside the function.

I would recommend a restructuring of `translate_string` like this:

```
def translate_string(string):
  translated_letters = [secret_translate(letter) for letter in string]
  return("".join(translated_letters))

trans_string = translate_string("arizona")
print(trans_string)
'nevmban'
```

This solution uses a list comprehension to loop over the letters of the input string, no need for an explicit loop with a counter. List comprehensions are very nice, they do need some getting used to. In addition, the function now returns the string instead of printing it inside the function. The None is gone, and you can use the translated string further along in your program, e.g. as input to another function.